# Array of pointers to pointers where values are known at compile-time

Tags: c++

I am implementing a look-up table of hard coded values and it would be useful if I could do something like this:

```
double *table[rows];
table[0] = {1.0, 4.32};
table[1] = {2.0, 3.22};
```

The important thing is it needs to have the type: double**

My solution at the moment is to have an array of arrays that is then turned into a double** one row at a time - but this is a bit of a hack...

This table needs to be passed to a function:

```
double NearestNeighbour(double** table, int width, int height, double key[])
```

where `width` and `height` are the dimensions of the input table.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use a `std::map<int, double*>`

Comment: @Cyber or `map<int, array<double, N>>`

Comment: @macbe can you modify the function that expects the `double **` to actually expect `double (*)[N_COLS]` ?

Comment: "it needs to have the type: double**"??? Where does `double **` fit in? Where is `double **` in your example? You need to explain clearer what is "it" that needs to have `double **` type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think I can because the function needs to be able to accept multiple look-up tables, each with different dimensions.

Comment: @macbe How does the function know how many columns there are? It would help to post the declaration of the function you need to call (perhaps along with some explanation)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The function is declared as: double NearestNeighbour(double** table, int width, int height, double key[]) where width and height are the dimensions of the input table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11 allows literals of class type, you can build the table out of literals which have a member function returning `double *`:

```
#include <array>

double *table[] = 
{
    &std::array<double, 3>{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }[0]
,   &std::array<double, 3>{ 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 }[0]
};
```

However this is pretty ugly. Especially considering that you manually have to remember the table width when it comes time to call `NearestNeighbour`.

Your existing solution (or a version of it that only builds the table once and saves it, and retains the number of columns automatically) is probably best.

---

If at all possible, see if you can modify NearestNeighbour. First of all, if it does not modify the table then it should have been written to take `double const *const *table`. Then you can pass a `const` table to it.

If you have access to the source code of it then you could reimplement it as a template function to accept an array of any element type, e.g.

```
template<typename RowT, size_t NumRows> 
double NearestNeighbour( RowT (&table)[NumRows], double *key )
{
    // here access table[row][col]
    // or even more generally, iterate over begin(table[row]), end(table[row])
}
```

Using the template does have the downside that the template has to appear in the header though.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can always do

```
const double table2d[2][2] = 
{
  { 1.0, 4.32 },
  { 2.0, 3.22 }
};

const double *const table[2] = 
{
  table2d[0],
  table2d[1]
};
```

assuming `table2d` is declared with static storage duration.

Comment: This is essentially my solution at the moment, but with the initialisation of table bundled up in a loop.